Can I replace haven't with ain't or didn’t for present tense?
Example:
I still ain’t found a comfortable grip on my racket.
Or
I still didn’t found a comfortable grip on my racket.

ain't is hillbilly speak, not proper English

the second choice should be I still didn’t find ...

"Have not" is formal.
"Haven't" is informal, and regularly used. It's acceptable everywhere except formal writing.
"Ain't" is accent or dialect. It's generally only used if you grew up with a dialect where "ain't" is normal or you are reporting or portraying the speech of someone with that accent/dialect.
(P.S.  Your rendition of the more formal version of the sentence is wrong. It should be:

I still haven't found a comfortable grip on my racket.

or

I still didn't find a comfortable grip on my racket.

Either would be acceptable in informal situations.)

And even in those dialects, it's usually a substitute for "are not" or "am not", not "have not".

@Barmar Often but not exclusively. The OP's example is a good one.

Hence "usually". I think the OP's example seems to be less common within those dialect communities than other uses of "ain't".

@Barmar: evidence? I think it's very common among speakers of those dialects.

@ColinFine Just personal experience, although I'm not actually in that community.

I'd say ain't was informal rather than dialect. In Britain it transcends class, or used to.

@Barmar: Me neither!

@MichaelHarvey: "Used to" is doing some heavy lifting! I don't think it's been upper-class for more than a century. And I'm dubious that ain't for haven't was ever upper-class.

@ColinFine - I am past retirement age...

@MichaelHarvey Me too

Back 100 years ago in Britain "ain't" was a classic indicator of working class. Shaw used it for Eliza Doolittle all the time, until Henry Higgins corrected her. You could say it was "cockney accent" but cockney was very much a working class accent.. Same with the northern accents.

@ColinFine - The upper classes in Dorothy L Sayers and Anthony Trollope say 'ain't', and Virginia Woolf used it in a 1938 letter, so, perhaps, as you say, if not a century, then not far off. The OED (2nd Ed, 1989) says The contraction is also found as a (somewhat outmoded) upper-class colloquialism.

I stand corrected. Can't argue with the OED.

@DJClayworth - go on, I dare you!

Short answer:

Still ain't found is valid but non-standard
Still didn't found is not common in any dialect


Still Ain't Found
You can find examples of "still ain't found" being used by native speakers.  But these would be speakers of dialectical English, NOT "standard" English.
Here are some examples, which all come from either African American Vernacular English, or Southern American English (two dialects with considerable overlap):

Still ain't found the "quit" button

Tweet

Still Ain't Found It Yet

Greg Johnson - Still Ain't Found It Yet

Astounding how I still ain't found me

[Still] Can’t Get Right

I still ain't found what I was after

Going Back To Indiana  (1970)

We still ain't found sh*t

Spaceballs

Still didn't found
You can find examples of this phrase, too, but it's almost exclusively in Internet forums.  The examples see to me to either be non-native, or typos.
